# Qt plainTextEdit jump to line

Tags: qt

I wirte a codeEdit based on plainEdit, and I need to move to specified line.  The below code relize the function patially. The proplem is that the cursor is on the bottom of the widget. Is there some way to put the cursor (yellow line) in the middle of the widget.

```
void MainWindow::run(){

    QTextCursor text_cursor(SPUEdit->document()->findBlockByNumber(100));
    SPUEdit->setTextCursor(text_cursor);
//    SPUEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(12);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call [centerCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#centerCursor) method of `QPlainTextEdit`:

> void QPlainTextEdit::centerCursor()
>
> Scrolls the document in order to
> center the cursor vertically.